# Issues with comparing two generic objects

Tags: java, comparison, binary-search-tree

My project is a Phonebook that is using `BSTree<E>`. Each node of the tree is `BTNode<E>`. In the main class, I replace E with Pair class, which has `(String name, String number)`, when I define the nodes.

I have the following comparator class to compare between 2 E types:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BTNodeComparator<E> implements Comparator<E>
{
    public int compare(E a, E b) throws ClassCastException
    {
        return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

and I use it in `BSTree<E>`.

Now, when I run the program and it comes to the comparator, it gives me errors at the comparator because now it compares between two Pairs

How can I solve this issue? What I want is to compare between the names of the two pairs ?

Sorry for my bad explanation. My English is weak.

=========================

Edit:

@Tim: After trying your solution it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Pair.compareTo(Pair.java:36) // @ return name.compareTo(pair.getName());
    at Pair.compareTo(Pair.java:2)  // @ public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>
    at BTNodeComparator.compare(BTNodeComparator.java:24) // @ return (a.compareTo(b));
    at BTNodeComparator.compare(BTNodeComparator.java:20) // @ public class BTNodeComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<E>
    at BSTree.search(BSTree.java:285)
    at BSTree.insert(BSTree.java:300)
    at PhoneBook.main(PhoneBook.java:25)
```

BTW, I decleared BTNodeComparator in BSTree as follows:

```
protected Comparator<E> c = new BTNodeComparator();
if (c.compare(target, cursor.getElement()) < 0) cursor = cursor.getLeft();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible failure I could see is `ClassCastException`.
To fix your code you will need to specify your `Pair` class like this:

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    String name;
    String number;

    //some implementation stuff...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

In general, if your `Comparator` implementation relies on the generic type implementing `Comparable` then you should specify it like this:

```
public class BTNodeComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<E> {
    public int compare(final E a, final E b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Doing so just gives you compile time safety without changing the semantics of how the `Comparator` works.

Based on your comment, I'm guessing you are embedding your `BTNodeComparator` into the `BSTree` class as a nested inner-class, which means you probably can't make that change without changing the type definition in the `BSTree` declaration.

Comment: How can I declare BTNodeComparator in BSTree<E> class, is it like this: Comparator<E> c = new BTNodeComparator(); ?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, I edited/re-organized my answer. The main take away is that I am assuming that Pair must implement Comparable. If you posted the exception and stack trace you are getting a more definitive answer could be given.

Comment: Take a look on my new post above